# Construction of compound (or maybe complex) sentences with comparative adjectives in each clause

Tags: sentence-construction, comparative-constructions

Could you, please, correct my sentences if they are incorrect?

1. The more angry the Hulk gets, the stronger he is.
2. The more people subscribe to my channel, the less I go out for walking (or go out walking or go out for a walk?)

Answer (score 0):

They are largely correct. I would use "angrier" rather than "more angry".

I would also use "go out walking". "go out for a walk" is perfectly fine normally, but it is normally used to refer to a *single walk*. In this case you want to refer to walking in general.

"go out for walking" does not sound correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence 1 is correct as it stands. However, using "angrier" in place of "more angry" would make this flown better, and sound mote natural, in my view. Using "becomes" in place of "is" at the end would emphasize that this is a process of change, not a state of being. so:

> 1A The angrier the Hulk gets, the stronger he becomes.

Sentence 2 is a little awkward. "The more people" could be using "more" to indicate the number of people (as it almost surely is  here) or the degree of subscription. This could be clarified by rephrasing as "the more subscribers to my channel I get". The phrase "I go out for walking" is non-standard, perhaps actually incorrect. I would favor simply  "I go out walking". Leading to:
\

> 2A  The more subscribers to my channel I get, the less I go out walking.

Comment: "The angrier the Hulk got, the stronger he became" is correct?

Comment: Yes I think so, @Voa Do you think it is wrong? if so, why?

Comment: Just asking for confirmation, because I never saw such sentences in the past tense.

Comment: It could also be written in the4 present tense. Which would be used depends on the rest of the text, in short on the context. But either is grammatically fine as an isolated statement.